# getaddrinfo: Servname not supported for ai_socktype (SocketError) - Rails Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, ubuntu

I am trying to start my rails server and rails console i am getting this all time yesterday it was working fine but today I just started my laptop and try to start rails server, i am getting this ai_socketype error. I have search many question but no body has proper answer for this. I am attaching my error log with it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    58: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    57: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    56: from /home/dell/cardinal/ch-job-marketplace/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    55: from /home/dell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    54: from /home/dell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    53: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    52: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    51: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    50: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    49: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    48: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    47: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    46: from /home/dell/cardinal/ch-job-marketplace/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    45: from /home/dell/cardinal/ch-job-marketplace/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    44: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    43: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    42: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    41: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    40: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    39: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    38: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    37: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    36: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    35: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
    34: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
    33: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    32: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
    31: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    30: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    29: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    28: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    27: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    26: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    25: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    24: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/dead_end-1.1.7/lib/dead_end/auto.rb:30:in `require_relative'
    23: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/dead_end-1.1.7/lib/dead_end/auto.rb:30:in `require'
    22: from /home/dell/cardinal/ch-job-marketplace/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    20: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    19: from /home/dell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    18: from /home/dell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    17: from /home/dell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    16: from /home/dell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    15: from /home/dell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    14: from /home/dell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    13: from /home/dell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    12: from /home/dell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    11: from /home/dell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    10: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
     9: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
     8: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
     7: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/barnes-0.0.9/lib/barnes/railtie.rb:44:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
     6: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/barnes-0.0.9/lib/barnes.rb:47:in `start'
     5: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/barnes-0.0.9/lib/barnes.rb:47:in `new'
     4: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/statsd-ruby-1.5.0/lib/statsd.rb:306:in `initialize'
     3: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/statsd-ruby-1.5.0/lib/statsd.rb:451:in `connect'
     2: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/statsd-ruby-1.5.0/lib/statsd.rb:451:in `synchronize'
     1: from /home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/statsd-ruby-1.5.0/lib/statsd.rb:463:in `block in connect'
/home/dell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/statsd-ruby-1.5.0/lib/statsd.rb:463:in `connect': getaddrinfo: Servname not supported for ai_socktype (SocketError)
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code that is failing?

Comment: I am just trying to start rails s and rails c i am unable to that because of this